# understanding premises

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Why is (A or C) not a premise used for D in the first problem and (A or B) a premise used for c in the second problem? I'm having trouble identifying premises in the proofs.

[problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqtlP.jpg)

[problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6eZL.jpg)

Comment: Were these pictures supposed to be of whole proofs?

Comment: yes but i just want to understand how you can identify the first premise by looking at the given statement if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

There are bracketss missing in problem 1 . To be unambiguous it should  (I assume) say  :Prove that $$[((A\lor C)\to D)\land (\neg B)\land (A\lor B)]\implies D.$$ We have $[(\neg B)\land (A\lor B)]\implies A.$  So we have $A.$ And $A\implies  (A\lor C).$ So we have $(A\lor C),$ which implies $D.$

$A\lor C$ is deduced from $(\neg B)\land (A\lor B).$